# zypper always install devel packages

Tags: linux, installation, zypper

Is there an option to force zypper to always install the `${PKG}-devel` packages to the packages I install via `zypper in $PKG`, maybe in a config or cmd?  I did not see any but would love to be able to use that on my devel machine, to spare me a lot of typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really a switch, but you can write a small wrapper script. This is an example of how it could look like:

```
#! /bin/sh

i=1

while true
do
    if [ "$(echo "$@" | cut -d " " -f$i)" = "" ] 
    then
        break
    else
        echo "PACKAGE"
        zypper in "$(echo "$@" | cut -d " " -f$i)"
        echo "PACKAGE-DEVEL"
        zypper in "$(echo "$@" | cut -d " " -f$i)-devel"
        i=$(expr $i + 1)
    fi
done
```

You can adjust the zypper commands as you wish, e.g. answering all questions with yes by default.

Comment: That only works for packages which actually have a development package. I also will probably hack the source itself rather than creating wrapper scripts. Nevertheless, it is kind of a solution.